# Unable to raise ValidationError in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, try-except, raise, validationerror

I have made a form in which the user is supposed to enter date and time. I want to make sure that the time is in the correct format so I wrote `convert_to_time` function so that it can raise a ValidationError when the format of time is wrong but it is not working the way I want. I want to display the error in the form itself. I seem that the `Exception` is not working. I mean the control is never going inside the `Exception` part.

Here is my forms.py file.

```
"""Function to convert string to time."""
def convert_to_time(date_time):
    format = '%H:%M:%S'
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time, format).time()
    except Exception:
        #print("qkftio")   This statement does not get executed even when the time format is wrong
        raise ValidationError(
                "Wrong time format entered."
            )

"""class used for booking a time slot."""
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_in_time', 'check_out_time',
                    'person', 'no_of_rooms']

    """Function to ensure that booking is done for future."""
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        normal_book_date = cleaned_data.get("check_in_date")
        normal_check_in = cleaned_data.get("check_in_time")
        convert_to_time(str(normal_check_in))
```

Here is my models.py file.

```
"""class used when a user books a room slot."""
class Booking(models.Model):
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    check_in_time = models.TimeField()
    check_out_time = models.TimeField()
    PERSON = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
    )
    person = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PERSON, default=1)
    no_of_rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(1)], default=1
        )
```

Can someone help?

Edit:
Here is my views.py file.

```
def booking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['normal_book_date'] = request.POST['check_in_date']
            request.session['normal_check_in'] = request.POST['check_in_time']
            request.session['normal_check_out'] = request.POST['check_out_time']
            request.session['normal_person'] = int(request.POST['person'])
            request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'] = int(
                request.POST['no_of_rooms']
                )
            response = search_availability(request.session['normal_book_date'],
                                           request.session['normal_check_in'],
                                           request.session['normal_check_out'],
                                           request.session['normal_person'],
                                           request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'])
            if response:
                context = {
                    'categories': response,
                    'username': request.user.username
                    }
                return render(request, 'categories.html', context)
            return HttpResponse("Not Available")
        else:
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'username': request.user.username
                }
            return render(request, 'book.html', context)
    context = {
        'form': BookingForm(),
        'username': request.user.username
        }
    return render(request, 'book.html', context)
```

This is the link to my github repo https://github.com/AnshulGupta22/room_slot_booking

Edit 2: This is the screenshot of the output that I am getting[image: Screen shot of output]

I want the error to be displayed in the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you raise validation errors inside an `is_valid`

I also changed the error type, to it attaches the error to the field itself and the message will show when you render the view with the failed form

```py
"""class used for booking a time slot."""
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_in_time', 'check_out_time',
                    'person', 'no_of_rooms']

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(BookingForm, self).is_valid()
        # ^ Boolean value

        format = '%H:%M:%S'
        try:
            # Note: `self.cleaned_date.get()`
            datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time')), format).time()
        except Exception:

            self.add_error('check_in_time', 'Wrong time format entered.')
            valid = False

        return valid
```

---

#### Edit

I cloned your project and changed the form to this and I got the error messages to render in the template

Just make sure all your validation is inside `is_valid()` and it should always work.
And for `add_error` just put the field that the msg should show up for.

##### hotel\forms.py

```py
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_in_time', 'check_out_time',
                    'person', 'no_of_rooms']

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(BookingForm, self).is_valid()

        # Always Check that it's NOT None before using it
        #   if self.cleaned_data.get('field'):
        #       # do custom validation
        #   else:
        #       # already failed validation

        # Validate both Check-in & Check-out
        for i in ['check_in_time', 'check_out_time']:
            if self.cleaned_data.get(i):
                if str(self.cleaned_data.get(i)).count(':') != 3:
                    self.add_error(i, 'Wrong time format entered.')
                    valid = False

        # Both values are Valid, now make sure check-out is after check-in
        if valid and self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time') and self.cleaned_data.get('check_out_time'):
            if self.cleaned_data.get('check_out_time') < self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time'):
                self.add_error('check_out_time', 'You can\'t check-out before check-in.')


        if self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_date'):
            now = timezone.now()
            if self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_date') < now.date():
                self.add_error('check_in_date', 'You can only book for future.')
                valid = False

            if valid:
                # Now validate Date & Time
                if (self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_date') == now.date() and
                    self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time') < now.time()):
                    self.add_error('check_in_date', 'You can only book for future.')
                    self.add_error('check_in_time', 'You can only book for future.')
                    valid = False

        return valid
```

Also you should add a `requirements.txt` file to your repo with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
This was mine after running your project:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==4.1.2
djangorestframework==3.14.0
pytz==2022.5
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.5
```

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time'), format).time(), here self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time') format should be string. Once I write str(self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_time')), same problem occurs.

Comment: Edit your original question and add the `view` that you are using & make sure you are calling `form.is_valid()` ..so is the problem that the form isn't rendering with the error message?

Comment: I have added the function in the views.py file and also the link to my GitHub repo.

Comment: I played around with your Repo and edited my answer. Don't use any `raise` calls and do all your validation inside the `is_valid()` and **not** the `clean()`

Comment: I do not know how you were able to run your code because the BookingForm() you wrote contains errors even when I corrected those errors, I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: I've edited my code block, fixing the syntax errors and I triple tested it. Delete your **entire** `BookingForm()` and paste that code block in.. **There shouldn't be any `clean()` function or any `raise` calls what-so-ever**.. If it still doesn't work, I'ma need some *actual* feedback of **why**, not just a ~'still not working' - ex) what does `print(form.errors)` say after it failed the `is_valid()`?- is it *even* failing `is_valid()`?- is the Template re-rendering?- is there just a crash?- something, anything.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot of the output.

Comment: Okay, I ran into that issue as well.. Django's default TimeField requires the seconds as well; so: `02:00:00` You're probably going to have to override the field to **not** have the seconds, but that's a different question.

Comment: It seems you never understood my question. I want that if the user enters the time in a wrong format, then an error should be displayed in the form itself to tell him to enter the time in correct format.

Comment: See, this is way feedback other than ~'it's not working' is important. I just presumed at the *very least* your try/catch was a valid way of checking. I was so focused on the errors not showing up, because that whole part was also wrong, that I discounted the entire underlying logic was bad. Edited my block.

Comment: Look my code was working correctly. I mean it was giving the same output that your code is giving. My main problem was that it was not displaying the error in the form itself. This is exactly what I mentioned in my question. Actually, **the problem is that it is not going inside the exception block**. If you can help me with that then that would be very nice. Besides your edited code just counts the number of : but this can be easily bypassed. Just because the number of : is 3 does not mean that the format is correct.